# Is there a tool to tell me what CSS class(es) are being used to style a specific element?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea why all my text elements are italicized.  Is there a tool that will let me identify an element on screen or at the source and tell me all the styles that cascaded to format this element?

Answer (score 3):

in Google Chrome, if you bring up the console by clicking F12.
Go to the Elements tab.
In here you can click on all elements, and to the right, you can see classes, and their styles, attacted to the element you clicked on.

Comment: Does this display the most recently applied style at the top?

Comment: Yes it does. And as you go down the list, it shows which style elements were overridden each time.